# Programmatically selecting a value in kendo-dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

It appears to not be possible to programmatically select a specific value in the Kendo `DropDownList` element. I checked the [API](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/DropDownListComponent/), but wasn't able to find something to trigger this.

There is a `selectionChange` event, but this is triggered by manually selecting a value from the dropdown. I'm interested in *programmatically* selecting an event; is there any way to do this?

Comment: The value of the component is defined by its `value` property binding. That being said, you will either need to set the value through the `[value]="selected value here"` or setting the ddlInstance.value property directly. Could you elaborate a bit more on exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the dropdown html tag: `(selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"`

And add the following to your typescript code:

```
protected selectionChange(value): void {
    console.log("The current value is: " + value)
}
```

To change the selected item from the code behind, use this: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/DropDownListComponent/#toc-value

Comment: That fires when I *manually* change the value to be something else. What I'm interested is telling the code I want to have a certain value set.

Comment: You asked how to trigger the selectionChange event

Comment: My apologies, I clarified the question.

Comment: Ah, I guess my eyes skipped that part, that's exactly what I wanted; many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Kendo does not take the new value unless we trigger the change event for the drop-down list. Once we set the value we have to trigger the change event

```
var menulist = $("#menulist").data("kendoDropDownList");
menulist.value("Top");
menulist.trigger("change");
```

Comment: Shouldn't line 2 be menulist?